How to implement Stability.ai API in Swift
I am trying to access the stability.ai API from a Swift App. The documentation gives examples in Python, javascript and CURL but not Swift.  They seem straightforward but I'm getting an error regarding the content-type as follows:
My code is:
 var request = URLRequest(url: url)
 request.setValue( authValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
 let boundary = "------------------------some_boundary"
 request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
 let accept = "image/*"
 request.setValue(accept, forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
 request.httpBody = parametersJson
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { 
//perform fetch
}

The error I get is:
{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Malformed FormData request. No initial boundary string (or you have a truncated message).\"}")

For reference, here is the API reference:
How to use
Please invoke this endpoint with a POST request.


The headers of the request must include an API key in the
authorization field. The body of the request must be
multipart/form-data. The accept header should be set to one of the
following:
image/* to receive the image in the format specified by the
output_format parameter.


application/json to receive the image encoded
as base64 in a JSON response.

However, it also says:

content-type required string non-empty Example: multipart/form-data
The content type of the request body. Do not manually specify this
header; your HTTP client library will automatically include the
appropriate boundary parameter.

And here is the sample code for cURL (that does not seem to mention multipart/form-data:
curl -f -sS "https://api.stability.ai/v2beta/stable-image/generate/sd3" \
  -H "authorization: Bearer sk-MYAPIKEY" \
  -H "accept: image/*" \
  -F prompt="Lighthouse on a cliff overlooking the ocean" \
  -F output_format="jpeg" \
  -o "./lighthouse.jpeg"

I should note that if I do not send the content-type in the header, it gives error:
{\"name\":\"bad_request\",\"errors\":[\"content-type: must be multipart/form-data\"]}

What is the correct way to send this request to the Stability.api API?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Since it's multipart form data, I'd expect to add the prompt and output_format in different settings, not just raw json. Look for multipart form data and not raw JsON in the httpBody
